# Display current time in this format: HH:mm:ss

Tags: c#, time, cultureinfo

I'm having some trouble displaying the time in this format: HH:mm:ss.
No matter what i try, i never get it in that format.

I want the time in the culture of the Netherlands which is "nl-NL".

This was one of my (although i forgot to keep the count) 1000th try:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");

string s = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss", ci);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: TimeSpan has a wimpy ToString() method.  Changed in .NET 4.0, not for the better.  Just lose "TimeofDay'.  Darin got it right of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396389.aspx) class, here's how to show the current time in the Eastern Standard Time time zone in HH:mm:ss format:

```
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
string s = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timeZone).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

To find all the timezones available, you can use

```
TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
```

Looking through the returned value from the above, the Id for the time zone you need (Amsterdam I assume) is called W. Europe Standard Time:

```
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
string s = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timeZone).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thanks thebunringmonk! That did the trick. Can't believe how long i've been looking for a solution to fix this!

Comment: @Yustme - No probs, glad I could help ;-) Globalization is not that well covered as not many of us do it, I did come across some good MSDN article on it a while back but can't seem to find the link now, will post an update if I find it again.

Answer (score 23):

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Hi,

I tried that one too, it adds the 'am/pm' stuff behind it.
How can i prevent that? Shouldn't cultureinfo be added?

Comment: @Yustme: Don't be confused between `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` and `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 1):

TimeOfDay is a TimeSpan, which has only one ToString() without parameters.
Use [Darin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3381717/662581) or a sample from [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for TimeSpan.ToString()

Comment: Here is the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_properties.aspx